# Laravel Queue not inserting into the table, but the work still executes

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue

So i am trying to create a queued job but it doesn't get added to the database or `php artisan queue:listen database` does not show anything. However, the work inside the `handle()` function gets executed.

The Job class:

```
class OrderCreatedJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct() {
        //
    }

    public function handle() {
        Notification::route('mail', 'my@email.com')->notify(new TestNotif());
    }
}
```

Controller function (also note that the addMinutes delay never happens, its sent straight away)

```
public function jobTest() {
    $this->dispatch((new OrderCreatedJob())->delay(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(1)));
}
```

In .env I have the `QUEUE_DRIVER=database` added as well.

So the issue is the email is being sent but it is being done straight away, and the browser still takes time for the request. The job also doesnt appear in the database, neither does the delay work as well.

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the fix was to have `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database` inside the env file, instead of `QUEUE_DRIVER=database`